# Calculator (Qalculate) doesn't show up on Ubuntu 18

Tags: lubuntu, calculator

I was not happy with the default calculator application as it didnt show up on any of my screen, so I uninstalled it. Checking other apps I installed Qalculate which requires permission to have access to my home folder.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: How did you installed the Qalculate? Please add output of `snap list | grep -i Qalculate` and `dpkg -l | grep -i Qalculate` to the question.

Comment: I installed it from ubuntu software. i uninstalled and i have no intention to install it again.

I wrote the answer to my problem but it was deleted. Although it is not the best solutions, i think that would help other users to move on.

The reason basically was that i have 3 screens. I removed 2 of them and i saw the calculator again.